# How to draw circle overlay on MapKit that surrounds several annotations/coordinates?

Tags: ios, swift, geometry, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have an array `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]`, I would like to draw a circle on `MKMapView` surrounding all these coordinates.

I have managed to draw a circle around a single `CLLocationCoordinate2D` as such:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 53, longitude: 27)
self.mapView.add(MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: 100))

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        guard overlay is MKCircle else { return MKOverlayRenderer() }

        let circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        circle.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
        circle.lineWidth = 1
        return circle
    }
}
```

How can I draw a circle that surrounds/encompasses all coordinates?, like below:

[image]

Comment: You need to find two annotations which have maximum distance and assume this distance as diameter of circle and update circle for new diameter.

Comment: Thanks for response, pulling my hairs out to get exactly this working, yet far from success

Comment: let me know if you get any problem

Comment: Glad you keen to help, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with `MKCoordinateRegion` initializer, which provides the region of the coordinates, the extension has a computed property to provide the radius of the region.

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    
    init?(from coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
        guard coordinates.count > 1 else { return nil }
        
        let a = MKCoordinateRegion.region(coordinates, fix: { $0 }, fix2: { $0 })
        let b = MKCoordinateRegion.region(coordinates, fix: MKCoordinateRegion.fixMeridianNegativeLongitude, fix2: MKCoordinateRegion.fixMeridian180thLongitude)

        if let a, let b, let result = [a, b].min(by: { $0.span.longitudeDelta < $1.span.longitudeDelta }) {
            self = result
        } else if let result = a ?? b {
            self = result
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var radius: CLLocationDistance {
        let furthest = CLLocation(latitude: self.center.latitude + (span.latitudeDelta / 2),
                                  longitude: center.longitude + (span.longitudeDelta / 2))
        return CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude).distance(from: furthest)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private
    private static func region(_ coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D],
                               fix: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D,
                               fix2: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MKCoordinateRegion? {
        let t = coordinates.map(fix)
        let min = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: t.min { $0.latitude < $1.latitude }!.latitude,
                                         longitude: t.min { $0.longitude < $1.longitude }!.longitude)
        let max = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: t.max { $0.latitude < $1.latitude }!.latitude,
                                         longitude: t.max { $0.longitude < $1.longitude }!.longitude)
        
        // find span
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(max.latitude - min.latitude, max.longitude - min.longitude)
        
        // find center
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: max.latitude - span.latitudeDelta / 2,
                                            longitude: max.longitude - span.longitudeDelta / 2)
        
        return MKCoordinateRegion(center: fix2(center), span: span)
    }
    
    private static func fixMeridianNegativeLongitude(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        guard (coordinate.longitude < 0) else { return coordinate }
        
        let fixedLng = 360 + coordinate.longitude
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: fixedLng)
    }
    
    private static func fixMeridian180thLongitude(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        guard (coordinate.longitude > 180) else { return coordinate }
        
        let fixedLng = -360 + coordinate.longitude
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: fixedLng)
    }
    
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = self.mapView.annotations.map{ $0.coordinate }
if let region = MKCoordinateRegion(from: coordinates) {
    self.mapView.add(MKCircle(center: region.center, radius: region.radius))
}
```

**Result** is exactly what I want, with ability to handle coordinates crossing 180th meridian:

[image]